# What causes color artifacts on the strings while shooting guitars?

Tags: product-photography, aberration, hasselblad

We're doing a photoshoot of a guitar collection. The photos are coming out great, but there is a specific color aberration on the strings. The guitar strings are braided by a thin metal wire, which probably causes reflections and interference of the reflected light. (Please see the picture)

[image]

We've tried to get rid of the color errors but without any luck. Now we are quite desperate so any help would be greatly appreciated.

We're shooting on a Hasselblad H3Dii with a Hasselblad 80mm lens.

Comment: It would be useful to know what lighting setup you're using, or if you're using natural light. It's possible that this is just caused by reflected light, but there could be more to it than that. Have you tried adjusting the orientation of the camera slightly to see if it still does the same?

Comment: I was just going to suggest what @laurencemadill suggested. Try rotating the camera 45°. Does that change the "frequency" of the color shift pattern? Also, try changing the distance between the camera and the guitar. Does that change the frequency of the pattern, or the color shift of it?

Comment: If you are shooting raw and have Adobe products (others may have this as well) did you try using the moire correction brush and see if that affects it. There are also fringe correction adjustments there (this seems more likely to be a moire though, as suggested above).  Or... and painful though it is.. just clone one spot right down the whole string and overwrite it.

Comment: Zooming in, there are orange and blue artifacts in many locations. There is a large one between the two drawn arrows on the body. There are smaller artifacts on the adjacent string and orange and blue artifacts on the frets under the smaller strings to the left. There is a blue patch on the pickguard screw. I suspect that size of the particular artifacts in question are due to the lack of an anti-alias filter at the camera sensor...speculation but this is common in digital medium format. The windings on the string may be below the Nyquist limit.

Comment: Agree with the above, it looks a lot like artefacting due to moire caused by there not being an AA filter. The winding of the wire on the string is likely VERY close to a multiple of the pixel density as projected onto the sensor. 
Also the image looks rather soft, are you shooting wide open?

Comment: Why not just replace the strings with nylon or gut for the shoot?

Comment: Would a polarizer help here at all?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft nylon or gut strings on an electric guitar? First, the largest 3 strings in a nylon set are wire wound, just like steel strings, so that doesn't fix the problem. Second, nylon strings on an electric would look weirder than the orange/blue artifacts. Like, uncanny-valley weird.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft and others, we're shooting a collection of 350+ rare vintage guitars, replacing strings or retouching is not really a viable option :(

Comment: @benrudgers - I'm not familiar with the Nyquist limit concept. Do you know what can be done about it?

Comment: The only thing that can be done to deal with a signal sampled at less than the Nyquist frequency is to low-pass filter the input signal to satisfy the Nyquist frequency. That's exactly what an antialiasing filter in a camera does. Other than that, you have to perform signal processing to do your best to make the signal look right. But once aliasing has been recorded, the damage is done. The best you can do after that is just triage.

Comment: @user1118321 a polarizer wouldn't help, unless it's bad enough in quality to blur the image.

Comment: @scottbb on top of that, the moire artifacts caused by aliasing interact with the Bayer filter processing. What starts out as simple pixel intensity variations becomes color banding.

Comment: @MarkRansom Not only is your point great, I think it's the _correct_ point. Specifically, the blue and red filter sites each have half the spatial resolution that the sensor's site have. The green, filling in the the diagonals between the reds and blues, essentially have a rectangular grid skewed by 45°; the green spatial resolution is only diminished by a factor of 1.414, rather than the 2x reduction of R and B. The light blue – orange nature of the color aliasing, lacking green effects, and the rather large period of the color "wave", collectively hint at the R&B spatial resolution being ...

Comment: ... _just_ under-sampled, and the green spatial resolution being _just_ sufficiently sampled enough to exceed Nyquist. I postulate that if the Bayer CFA weren't there, with the sensor's native pixel resolution exceeding the green spatial frequency by 1.414, there wouldn't be _any_ grey-scale aliasing at all. Very nice catch Mark!

Answer (score 10):

We've just figured it out. As **Ben Rudgers** correctly pointed out, the problem is caused by the lack of anti-aliasing filter on the Hasselblad sensor. It produces much sharper pictures, but with a lot more moiré.

Knowing this, we've just used the **moiré reduction** feature in Lightroom. The feature is quite "hidden", but once we found it, it solved the issue completely for us.

You can read about the moiré correction feature here:

https://scottkelby.com/a-little-known-feature-of-photoshop-and-lightroom-to-the-rescue/

Thanks everyone for your comments!

Comment: This will happen with "flatwound" strings and those that are not single strand (monofilament-like) drawn strings without fine lines.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone reading this in the distant future 2021 and beoynd.

You can also remove the aliasing by capturing red, green and blue separately.

Assuming you are using a tripod, you can shoot with color filters or gels in front of the camera. (Or gels in front of strobes, but that requires a pretty dark room.)

Take one shot per red, green and blue color. Either shoot in black and white on the camera, or convert each shot to black and white in post.

Then, merge the three layers, with each layer representing red, green and blue. This can be done in Photoshop or with tools such as ImageMagick.

This will remove any aliasing, but requires that the setup is stable enough to not move the camera or subject between exposures.

The idea is [not a new one](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/early-color-photography-russia).

[image]